# How to I declare "LPTSTR" for Raku NativeCall?

Tags: raku

Raku/Perl6
Windows

I am trying to code a Raku Native call to a C functions that uses a "LPTSTR".  How do I declare that?   Something like `constant DWORD := int32;` but for LPTSTR?

If it helps, I found this description: "LPTSTR is a [long] pointer to a (non-const) TCHAR string" and "LPTSTR: null-terminated string of TCHAR (Long Pointer)"

"LPTSTR" comes from  "LPWSTR lpBuffer,"

Comment: [A google for 'TCHAR'](https://www.google.com/search?q=TCHAR) and ["long pointer"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22long+pointer%22) make it clear they are both platform specific. (cf the built in NativeCall type `int`, which is platform specific, versus `int32`, which is fixed and thus not platform specific.) If you want a portable solution you will need to take this into account. Perhaps there's already a module (or family of modules) that you can import that computes and defines a pile of constants like these, but [a search of m.r.o](https://modules.raku.org/search/?q=tchar) drew a blank.

Comment: You are asking for the wrong thing. The `LPTSTR` type is only relevant in the generic-text mapping macro (e.g. `FormatMessage`). That's purely a pre-processor symbol; there is no API called `FormatMessage`. If you want to call an API, you're going to have to decide, whether you want to call the Unicode or the ANSI version. You'll be passing an `LPWSTR` or `LPSTR`, respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LP = (long) pointer, TSTR = either a wide string if `UNICODE` is defined, or an 8-bit string if not. So it's either a `wchar_t *` or `unsigned char *`. Determining which of these is in effect for the library you're using is probably quite difficult from Raku-space.

Comment: Aiui "(long) pointer" is pretty generic in the broad scheme of things. Is it implicit in the context of Windows that it has some precise meaning, perhaps defined by VC++? Am I right in thinking that NativeCall does *not* define a precise equivalent to this "(long) pointer" -- i.e. portability issues apply, as I mentioned in my comment below the question, just as they do in relation to "`wchar_t *` or `unsigned char *`"?

Comment: "`wchar_t *` or `unsigned char *`" Aiui those are completely precise C types. Are there exactly corresponding built in native or NativeCall types? "Determining which of these is in effect for the library you're using is probably quite difficult from Raku-space." I think that elaboration of that point, with links to any related SOs if there are any you can find, would significantly improve your answer.

Comment: @raiph the "long" in long pointer is a relic from 16-bit memory models and means nothing on 32- or 64-bit Windows. All pointers are long, but the `LP` names are kept for historical reasons.

Comment: @raiph to the best of my knowledge `char *` is represented by `Str` and `wchar_t *` by `CArray[uint16]` but I'm not really sure.

Comment: "All pointers are long". I googled to better understand what you mean. Ainui modern compilers assume they are the same size as a native integer. So, if one is just specifying a pointer (i.e. Todd's scenario afaict), as against [its size](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/learnwin32/windows-coding-conventions?redirectedfrom=MSDN#pointer-precision-types), then, presumably, a suitably parameterized [`Pointer`](https://docs.raku.org/language/nativecall.html#Basic_use_of_pointers) (so `Pointer[Str]` or `Pointer[CArray[unint16]]`?), is the right Raku translation. Is that right?